# Get non-zero values from a QSqlQueryModel that contains NULL using PyQt5

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pyqt, pyqt5

I am querying from a SQL database and displaying the output using PyQt. I am using UNION ALL to combine two tables that share a column. They are both in the same schema (named schema).

Here are the tables:

table_1:

| number | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

table_2:

| number | letter_number |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT "number", "id", NULL::bigint AS "letter_number" 
FROM schema."table_1" 
UNION ALL
SELECT "number", NULL::bigint AS "id", "letter_number"
FROM schema."table_2";
```

The resulting table is:

| number | id | letter_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 |  | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |  |
| 4 |  | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |  |
| 6 |  | 2 |

I then use PyQt5 and Python to get the resulting values. I do not want to edit them. The query text is the same as above.

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlQueryModel
model = QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery(querytext)
for row in range(model.rowCount()):
    for column in range(model.columnCount()):
        index = model.index(row, column)
        print(model.data(index))
```

I get this for the output (I have formatted it to better display the problem):

```
1, 1, 0
2, 0, 2
3, 1, 0
4, 0 ,2
5, 1, 0
6, 0, 2
```

The NULL values come out as 0 (zero), how do I stop this and get something that is not a number (empty string, string that says 'NULL', etc.)? I use other tables that contain 0 as a value, so adding an if statement to change the zeros to anything else is out of the question.

I am currently displaying the model using PyQt's QTableView(). It may be possible to get the data from there instead, but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the schema? What kind of datacase is it? Please provide a proper [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Setting the query to be

```
SELECT NULL::text AS "example";
```

versus

```
SELECT NULL::bigint AS "example";
```

will produce different results when using

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlQueryModel
model = QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery(querytext)
for row in range(model.rowCount()):
    for column in range(model.columnCount()):
        index = model.index(row, column)
        print(model.data(index))
```

Using text will produce an empty string (`""`) when using `model.data(index)` for data gathering.

This is useful when using `UNION ALL` to concatenate two or more tables that contain zero (0) in their non-shared columns.

Now, I can't confuse a zero value from a column versus a zero being read from `NULL`.